# Cannot connect using Connect-MsolService

Tags: azure, powershell

Im using powershell to connect to azure but I´m not able to connect using `Connect-MsolService`. When I try using `Connect-AzureAD` it shows a prompt asking for my credentials and I enter it and it connects normally. But when I try using `Connect-MsolService` I put the same credentials on the prompt but it fails saying that the email or password is wrong (but its the same credentials for the `Connect-AzureAD` command).

Comment: The documentation of this modules (MSOnline) states that this is an older version of what is now "AzureAD" and encourages the use of AzureAD2 instead. so i guess this might just be an issue with an outdated module. why do you need "connect-msolservice" ? doesn't "connect-azuread" do the same thing essentially ?

Comment: because I need to use the cmdlets to troubleshoot a custom domain name verification. And I just found it on msol. Like `Confirm-MSolDomain -DomainName `

Comment: You can use `Confirm-AzureADDomain` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Confirm-AzureADDomain?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the latest AzureAD module.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/

Logon with `Connect-AzureAD`

Confirm Domain with `Confirm-AzureADDomain`